# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. SQL error in my laravel 8 project

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8, voyager

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pride-express`.`travel_planes`, CONSTRAINT `travel_planes_circuit_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`circuit_id`) REFERENCES `circuits` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `travel_planes` (`car_id`, `user_id`, `title`, `is_reservation_open`, `departure_time`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1, Roles, 1, 2021-06-10 07:02:00, 2021-06-10 04:06:39, 2021-06-10 04:06:39))

**Here is my circuit table migration:**

```
Schema::create('circuits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('circuit_slug')->unique();
        $table->string('departure');
        $table->string('destination');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Circuit model:**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Circuit extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    /**
    * Get the .. that owns the comment.
    */
   public function travelPlane()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(TravelPlane::class);
   }
}
```

[Circuit table Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bC3e.jpg)

**And below is my travel_planes migration table:**

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('travel_planes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('car_id');
        $table->foreign('car_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('cars')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('circuit_id');
        $table->foreign('circuit_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('circuits')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamp('departure_time');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->boolean('is_reservation_open')->default(true);
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

**TravelPlanes model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class TravelPlane extends Model{
use HasFactory;


   /**
   * Get the Trajectory for the travel.
   */
    public function circuit()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Circuit::class);
    }


 }
```

[Travel planes Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbWFG.jpg)

NB: data in the Travel planes table was generated by faker.

This error occured when I tried to add a new line in my *travel_plane* table using *voyager* admin panel.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This error Comes from travel_plane table witch has a foreign Key on witch you try to insert a value witch IS not available in the parent table.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The *circuit_id* foreign key was defined as I shown in my *travel_planes* Print Screen. I think the problem is from other things. Any Idea please  ?

Comment: Can you show us  the values of the parent table ???

Comment: I have joined *Circuit table Print Screen*  above. You can see it please.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem. Here is what is the issue:

In my *travel_plane* **BREAD** cretor I should check *add* and *edit* part at both the default column name and the relationship created by *voyager* .

See in this tow print screen what I mean.

[image: print screen for the default table column]
[image: print screen for the relationship column]